# Google App Engine - Hebrew characters are garbled on incoming email

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, jakarta-mail

I've created an GAE http servlet which should handle and moderate incoming emails.

When I receive and incoming message which contains Hebrew text it gets garbled.

For instance, when the following code will get an incoming mail message with Hebrew text:

```
public void doPost( HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp ) throws IOException {

       Message message = new MimeMessage( session, req.getInputStream() );
       System.out.print( message.getSubject() );
```

}

Will print something like: ××××§× or a set of question marks.

Answer (score 0):

## 1

Isn't the log is ISO-8859-1 by default?

I use this...

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
    <property name="file.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    property name="DEFAULT_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" />
</system-properties>
```

[System Properties and Environment Variables](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#System_Properties_and_Environment_Variables)

## 2

Don't you need to read it in the right encoding?  For example, I get Japanese mail in different encodings and to read it I have to use:

```
            InputStreamReader isr;

            if (message.getContentType().contains("ISO-2022-JP")) {
                        isr = new InputStreamReader(message.getInputStream(), "ISO-2022-JP");
            } else {
                        isr = new InputStreamReader(message.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to distinguish whether the characters are wrong or whether you're just **seeing** the wrong characters.  The String object returned by message.getSubject() will contain Unicode characters.  You can examine the numeric value of each of those Unicode characters to see if it's the correct character.

When you print those characters, all sorts of other character processing occurs.  The characters are probably written as UTF-8 or some other encoding.  The software you use to read those characters from the log file and display them on your screen has to expect the same character encoding that was used when the characters were written.  All sorts of mismatches are possible.